# Output Youtube video

Tags: jquery

I need to output youtube video via Ajax in my rails 3 App. There are other ways of doing it, but for js.erb, i need to do it in a different way.I want to display youtube video using jquery's html() method or some other method. I tried this:

```
$("#bt").click(function () {

      $("#vid").html("
   <object width="640" height="390"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/9QS0q3mGPGg?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>"+"<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/9QS0q3mGPGg?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="390"></embed></object>");
    });
```

But it is not displaying the video.Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Where does AJAX come into it?

Comment: It will be rendered in js.erb.That will make it Ajax.I was using pirobox, but it does not meet all my needs.Hence this.

Comment: @santu101: Erm, how so? I don't think AJAX means what you think it means (though I'm no expert on Rails).

Comment: Basically, i have a list of videos.Each item in the list is a video title.The title will have id like id="vid_<%=c.id%> and we use format=>:js and :remote=>true.Then in the controller, we respond with js.erb. In the js.erb, we render this.

Comment: @santu101: AJAX (better called XmlHttpRequest) deals with the handling of HTTP requests to a webserver after the initial pageload. It's used for dynamically loading content inline _during_ a page visit, after the main page content has already loaded. Basic DOM manipulation is _not_ AJAX.

Comment: I can explain why i think it is Ajax,but my language limits me.In short, the video url which is `http://www.youtube.com/v/9QS0q3mGPGg?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0` is stored in database. Upon request, this and some othe contents will be loaded in a lightbox i'm creating. It may not be Ajax in the proper sense.But similar to it. And it is all happening via an Ajax call. :)

Comment: @santu101: I don't think you have any AJAX whatsoever.

Comment: in rails 3, Ajax request looks like this:`<%=button_to 'Vote',vote_path(:format=>:js,:id=>c.id),:remote=>true%>` and that is what iam using. :)

Comment: @santu101: What's "voting" got to do with a YouTube `<object>`..?! I think I'll just leave you to it.

Comment: Hmmm difficult to explain. Voting is also sent via Ajax call. A video is playing and user votes for it.Video continues to play but a message fades in and fades out telling user the vote was successful.I will send you the link of my App when i get it online. :)

Comment: @santu101: OK, so it sounds like the voting using AJAX. But what that has to do with the `<object>` in your question is still beyond me: playing the YouTube video is not AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error with your syntax. You open and close your text with a **"**, but your text also contains **"**, changing it to **'** should make this work:

```
$('#bt').click(function () {
      $('#vid').html('<object width="640" height="390"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/9QS0q3mGPGg?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>"+"<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/9QS0q3mGPGg?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="390"></embed></object>');
    });
```